# How to get responsive Divs for Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm struggling with the one section of my site, in order to get it fully responsive for mobile devices etc. The rest of the site is great its just this section:

The site is: http://dev.strategix.co.za/
The divs im referring to is the blocks and right side content under OUR SOLUTIONS.

I have the blocks `.left2 {width:60%}` and right side content `.right2 {width:40%}`but obviously that isnt enough as you can see when viewing on mobile.

Please can someone assist. 
Thank you!

Comment: use media queries to make it responsive.

Comment: I see you built it using Wordpress Visual Composser. Why not use their grid to build those .left and .right column? It will be responsive automatically like the rest of the part of websites

Comment: create a container div around the content you want to segregate. How do you want it to be displayed? if you want the .left2 to be displayed above right2 in mobile view use media queries for different sizing in mobile and desktop view "@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {}"

Comment: use inline-block instead of float:left in .right2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `float:left` causes your problems with responsive layout. Remove it from `.right2`, and then give both `.left2` and `.right2` the style `display:inline-block`.

The rest is good as far as I can see. There's no margins, and you use `border-box`, so that looks good.

Comment: Hi Xahed, the inline-block seemed to work, i couldnt use float:left on .left2. however something still doesnt look right on mobile. can .right2 not drop under the boxes? looks to be taking up alot of width on mobile.

Comment: Then you need to use a mixture of the `inline-block`, and  _media queries_ as suggested by several people here. Googling for _fluid grid_ will turn up several tutorials on how to do this. I think one of the best tutorials is at : http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
.left2 {
width: 100%;
height: initial;
}

.right2 {
width: 100%;
}

.right2 .box2 {
padding: 2%;
float: left;
width: 96%;
margin-top: -2px;
}
}
```

Hope this helps you.